# JavaMailSenderImpl autowire error if spring.mail.host not in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, autowired

I am having a little "problem" using JavaMailSenderImpl to send emails in my spring boot application.

I am trying to set all properties dynamically (I will want them to be read from the DB in the future) but, for reasons unknown to me, autowiring JavaMailSenderImpl only works if "spring.mail.host" is present in my application.properties.

It doesn't matter the value I set (it can be empty, it doesn't matter because I set the right one later), but the property must be there or autowiring will fail.

This is my Controller:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class MailController {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSenderImpl ms;


    @RequestMapping("/mail")
    public String send(Model model){

        SimpleMailMessage message;
        String fromEmail="sdfsdf98435sadf@gmail.com";
        String toEmail ="xxxxxxx";

        Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");

        ms.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        ms.setPort(587);
        ms.setUsername("xxxx");
        ms.setPassword("yyyyy");
        ms.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);

        message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setSubject("Test email");
        message.setFrom(fromEmail);
        message.setTo(toEmail);
        message.setText("Something something");

        try{
            ms.send(message);
        }
        catch(MailException ex){
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return "OK";
    }

}
```

Will work fine (sends the email) with this application.properties:

```
#springboot-starter-mail properties
spring.mail.host=
```

But will throw this exception if I remove that line:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I could leave the empty property there but It doesn't feel right.

Any ideas what might be the cause?

Comment: The trigger for creating an `JavaMailSenderImpl` is the existence of the `spring.mail.host` property. Not being there is something different as being empty. Also what you are doing is something you shouldn't be doing in the first place. If you want your configuration from the database then do that, but don't reconfigure beans at runtime. Load all properties at startup (create a Jdbc driven PropertySource implementation) and let spring do the injection for you. Also why the database? Why not spring cloud config or something else.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks a lot for the explanation, I didn't know it was the trigger. It is an application that will allow users to send mails using their their email accounts. That information will be saved in a database for each user and thats why I set the properties on the fly. I don't know if there is a better solution for this case, I am no expert so any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Autowire the interface JavaMailSender instead of the implementation.

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;
```

Comment: And how do I set host, port, username, etc dynamically using JavaMailSender?

Answer (score 2):

Do not autowire the `JavaMailSenderImpl`. Instead create a method that creates and instance of `JavaMailSenderImpl` and returns it with all parameters you need. And then call your mail sender where you need it. If you autowire the mailsender it injects an instance which already needs the parameter `spring.mail.host`.