# How to reload configuration bean with properties from database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail, spring-bean

I need to create a spring javamail bean initialized with values from database for each mail sent. Based on this article, [How to Load Application Properties from Database](http://www.opencodez.com/java/how-to-load-application-properties-from-database.htm)

I've configured my `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to load values from both properties file and database. I have the following bean(`mailSender`) in my java configuration class for sending mail from my application which loads host, port, username and password from the database,

```
@Configuration
public class MailSenderConfig {
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSender.setHost(PropertiesUtils.getProperty("mail.server.host"));
        javaMailSender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(PropertiesUtils.getProperty("mail.server.port")));
        javaMailSender.setUsername(PropertiesUtils.getProperty("mail.server.username"));
        javaMailSender.setPassword(PropertiesUtils.getProperty("mail.server.password"));
        return javaMailSender;
    }
}
```

But my problem is when the database values changes the `mailSender` bean has the old values which is provided while starting the application context. For any changes to take place to the bean I need to restart the server for updating the bean values.

I inject this bean in my controller where I need to send a mail like this,

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;
```

Based on some suggestion, I tried to use `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` but it din't create a new bean definition(still has old values).

So what I need is, every time a mail is sent using this `mailSender` bean it should pick the values from database without restarting the context or server. Is it possible or how it can be done?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Similar question: [Spring: Refresh a bean created from code reading a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094419/spring-refresh-a-bean-created-from-code-reading-a-database)

Comment: You can try to use  Spring Cloud Config and  @RefreshScope annotation

Comment: No. Sorry I don't want to use Spring Cloud Config. I just have options bringing values from db and properties file.

Comment: Don't make it a spring bean. Inject a factory instead, which has a method `createMailSender()`, which creates a new sender each time it's called. Or use what Spring explains in its documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-method-injection

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. I've done something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/37439747/1793718 Create a new JavaMailSenderImpl object in `createMailSender()` and set parameters like host,port etc from database and return the new mailSender object every time I need to send mail and its working. But I don't understand from the documentaion on how to inject a bean factory method to create the `mailSender` bean. If you could provide me some example it would be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've create a custom mail service implementation and removed the Mail sender bean as JB Nizet suggested. In the service implementation I'm reading properties from the database and creating a new instance everytime a mail is sent from the application. Like below

```
@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;

JavaMailSenderImpl jms = mailService.createMailSender();
MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(mailService.getMailSession(jms));
MimeMessageHelper message = null;
message.setSubject("Test mail");
message.setTo("email@domain.com");
message.setText(htmlContent, true);
Transport.send(message);
```

where `createMailSender()` creates a new instance of `JavaMailSenderImpl` for every mail you send.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
public class CustomProperties extends Properties {

    private final AppLogger logger = AppLogger.getInstance();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String GET_QUERY = "select config_value from config_params where config_key = ?";
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public CustomProperties(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public String getProperty(String key) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(GET_QUERY, new Object[]{key}, String.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But with this above code the properties from database is not read. I'm getting null values instead.`getProperty` method is never called. So it throws `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:`